# Laravel Nova Metric Trend In Future

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm stuck I want to create a Laravel Nova Metrics Trend where it goes in the future  instead of back in time.

This code will output: 15-March-2019, 14-March-2019, 13-March-2019,

```
public function calculate(Request $request)
{
    return $this->sumByDays($request, Payment::class, 'hours_per_month', 'upcoming_invoice_date')->showLatestValue();
}

/**
 * Get the ranges available for the metric.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function ranges()
{
    return [
        3 =>  '3 Days',
    ];
}
```

I've already made some changes to Trend.php but it gave me nothing than errors.

```
    /**
 * Return a value result showing a sum aggregate over days.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|string  $model
 * @param  string  $column
 * @param  string  $dateColumn
 * @return \Laravel\Nova\Metrics\TrendResult
 */
public function sumByDays($request, $model, $column, $dateColumn = null)
{
    return $this->aggregate($request, $model, Trend::BY_DAYS, 'sum', $column, $dateColumn);
}
```

Is this even possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The trend range is defined in Trend.php so you were on the right track!

Check out the protected function aggregate.

```
protected function aggregate($request, $model, $unit, $function, $column, $dateColumn = null)
    {
```

The $endingDate can be changed to whatever you want!

```
        $possibleDateResults = $this->getAllPossibleDateResults(
            $startingDate = $this->getAggregateStartingDate($request, $unit),
            $endingDate = Chronos::now();
```

The Chronos API has nice documentation but try something like this

```
$endingDate = Chronos::tomorrow()->addWeeks(4),
```

Note: I have done very minimal testing on this so use at your own risk. It does break the showLatestValue() method for trend metrics, but that could be addressed in TrendResult.php if you really needed it.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can change the range dates to the future with a negative number (of days) as key:

```
public function ranges()
{
    return [
        -3 =>  'Next 3 Days',
    ];
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work because the order of datetimes will be wrong in the query as the endDate is always set to now() in Trend.php:

```
$startingDate = $this->getAggregateStartingDate($request, $unit),
$endingDate = Chronos::now(),
...
->whereBetween($dateColumn, [$startingDate, $endingDate])
```

2) Quick/dirty fix. In Trend.php change the whereBetween() second argument array (of datetimes) comparing and setting datetimes in ascending order.

```
->whereBetween(
    $dateColumn, 
    [ min($startingDate, $endingDate), max($startingDate, $endingDate) ]
)
```